# Publishing a Ruby on Rails website using Amazon S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upload, amazon-s3

I've completed my website using a Ruby on Rails framework, which uses a simple database.

I have set up an Amazon S3 account and would like to upload it to this, however I've been told that I would need more than just this to get the website working.

I am COMPLETELY new to uploading RoR websites, so would anyone be willing to talk me through what needs doing/ why?

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 is simply for storing static assets, images, css etc. You can run entirely static sites on it ie html but not 'applications'.

You may have misheard - you could use Amazon EC2 which provide you with a virtual server to host your application and run your application.

If you are entirely new to this process then I suggest you investigate the likes of Heroku (heroku.com) EngineYard, BrightBox, Rackspace etc With the first you probably would be able to use their free offering and deployment is simply by Git - there's no system administration involved.

Comment: Second the heroku thing. Note that heroku uses EC2 under the hood, so access to S3 files is fast. Store data on S3, app runs on a read only file system on heroku.